# Не работает подгрузка scss переменных в модуль

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, scss, vue3

Такой вопрос:
Почему в этом модуле(странице) импорт scss стилей работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в вот этом модуле нет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это вылечить?
Ошибка выглядит следующим образом:

```
 WAIT  Compiling...                                                                                                                                                                     03:25:49

98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                  03:25:50

 error  in ./src/components/header/headerTopNav/index.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=e58835c0&lang=scss&scoped=true

Syntax Error: SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
2 │ @import "../assets/scss/_variables.scss";
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  E:\Progi3\vue3-perfect-goods\src\components\header\headerTopNav\index.vue 2:9  root stylesheet


 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--9-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader
/src??ref--9-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--1-1!./src/components/
header/headerTopNav/index.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=e58835c0&lang=scss&scoped=true 4:14-487 15:3-20:5 16:22-495
 @ ./src/components/header/headerTopNav/index.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=e58835c0&lang=scss&scoped=true
 @ ./src/components/header/headerTopNav/index.vue
 @ ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--15-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--15-2!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--1-0!./node_modules/vue-l
oader-v16/dist??ref--1-1!./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts
 @ ./src/views/Home.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts
 @ ./src/views/Home.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.0.102:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.ts
```

Comment: относительный путь во втором скрине не правильный.  он должен начинаться с  ../../../   вроде

Comment: а какой вариант будет корректным во втором случае?
можно ли использовать какие то уникальные решения что бы работали в обоих случаях корректно?

Comment: ну если относительные использовать то   ../../../  вроде..короче попробовать  добавлять двоеточия со слешами

Comment: а абсолютный путь можно как то использовать?

Comment: зависит от настроек проекта.  не скажу точно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В файле `index.vue` указан неправильный путь до scss файла. Читайте подробней про [относительные и абсолютные пути](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%83#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%20%E2%80%94%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE,%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2.&text=%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C,%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9.), а также про [`..`,  `.` и `/`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3_(%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0)).

> а абсолютный путь можно как то использовать?

Можно, но это плохой вариант, лучше используйте [webpack resolve alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/).

Кроме этого, чтобы постоянно не импортировать файл переменных sass, смотрите в сторону webpack лоадера [sass-resources-loader](https://github.com/shakacode/sass-resources-loader).